# Error while compiling c program on AIX - "ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: .iconv_open"

Tags: c, aix, iconv

I am using `iconv_open()` function in my code but while compiling the code using cc I am getting error

> "ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol: .iconv_open "

here is my c code which I am trying to compile

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<iconv.h>

#define CONV_FAILED  ((iconv_t) -1)

int main(){
iconv_t some;
some = iconv_open("eucKR", "UTF-8");

if (some != CONV_FAILED){
        printf("%s \n", "something else");
        }
else    {
        printf("%s \n","error occurred");
        }
}
```

Error messages:

> bash-2.05a$ cc iconv.c ld: 0711-317 ERROR: Undefined symbol:
>   .iconv_open ld: 0711-345 Use the -bloadmap or -bnoquiet option to
>   obtain more information.

Also I used - bloadmap and this is file content generated by using it

```
(ld): halt 4
(ld): setfflag 4
(ld): savename a.out
(ld): filelist 6 1
(ld): i /lib/crt0.o
(ld): i iconv.o
(ld): lib /usr/vac/lib/libxlopt.a
(ld): lib /usr/vac/lib/libxlipa.a
(ld): lib /usr/vac/lib/libxl.a
(ld): lib /usr/lib/libc.a
LIBRARY: Shared object libc.a[shr.o]: 3243 symbols imported.
LIBRARY: Shared object libc.a[meth.o]: 2 symbols imported.
LIBRARY: Shared object libc.a[posix_aio.o]: 20 symbols imported.
LIBRARY: Shared object libc.a[aio.o]: 18 symbols imported.
LIBRARY: Shared object libc.a[pse.o]: 8 symbols imported.
LIBRARY: Shared object libc.a[dl.o]: 4 symbols imported.
LIBRARY: Shared object libc.a[pty.o]: 1 symbols imported.
FILELIST: Number of previously inserted files processed: 6
(ld): resolve
RESOLVE: 34 of 6664 symbols were kept.
(ld): addgl /usr/lib/glink.o
ADDGL: Glink code added for 3 symbols.
(ld): er full
ld: 0711-318 ERROR: Undefined symbols were found.
        The following symbols are in error:
 Symbol                    Inpndx  TY CL Source-File(Object-File) OR Import-File{Shared-object}
                              RLD: Address  Section  Rld-type Referencing Symbol
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 .iconv_open               [24]    ER PR iconv.c(iconv.o)
                                   0000001c .text    R_RBR    [12]    .main
ER: The return code is 8.
```

I want to know why this error is being generated, any leads would be appreciated.

Comment: Link with `libiconv`

Comment: Probably you have to specify the ICONV library. Please [edit] your question and show the commands you use to compile and link the program. Try to add `-liconv` to the link command.